# There was an error creating the child process for this terminal

Tags: scripting, linux-mint, terminal, kali-linux

I am new to Linux and I am using Linux mint(latest version). I was trying to install the lazy script by following a tutorial from the internet. This problem occurs every time I try to install the script.

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal. Failed to execute child process “bash /root/lscript/install.sh” (No such file or directory)
```

I've opened the directory that the terminal claims are empty but there is the directory with the necessary files.
 These are the codes to install the script:

```
cd lscript
apt-get update
git clone https://github.com/arismelachroinos/lscript.git
cd lscript
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
```

---

On a seperate note, can I install something made for kali Linux in ubuntu-based distro?